# How to get active sheet menu in PowerBuilder?

Tags: powerbuilder

How to get the active sheet menu in PowerBuilder. If I disable menu, it disables the last open sheet menu rather than the active sheet menu?

Comment: How did you "disable menu". You must work with sheet menu via `MenuID` sheet instance variable.

Comment: Actually I was not getting menu ID rather I was disabling menu directly by doing m_sheet.file.enabled = false. Now, from your query I tried to get the menu Id and then disable the menu based on the menu ID and its worked. Thanks e.g; m_sheet  lm_setupMenu
lm_setupMenu = This.menuID
lm_setupMenu.m_new.enabled = False

Comment: You can answer your own question if you want. It might make the question more helpful to others who don't read the comments.

Answer (score 1):

> Waseem Kiyani answered this Dec 4 '12 at 14:28

Actually I was not getting menu ID. Rather, I was disabled the menu directly

```
m_sheet.file.enabled = false
```

Thanks to Maximus, I disabled the menu item by using the menu Id.

*Example:*

```
m_sheet lm_setupMenu
lm_setupMenu = This.menuID
lm_setupMenu.m_new.enabled = False
```

Comment: Hello, based on what is said here, please for a "WindowType=main!" How can I hide the menu to dynamically modify it and then activate it? What you say only works in mdi

Comment: @Eduardo G: I think this is oimportant enough to ask a new question and, maybe, give more details.